# Why does missing image display broken image and not the text from alt tag in Chrome?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So the rails code I used:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
```

produces the HTML:

```
<img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/images/logo.png" />
```

But when I load the page, it shows the broken image symbol.

What gives?

I am loading it in the latest stable build of Chrome on Windows, fyi.

As an aside...it shows the text and works perfectly in Firefox on Windows. But Chrome breaks it.

Comment: What does Safari on Windows show? I would expect the same behavior as Chrome.

Comment: Not sure. Don't have it installed, but I imagine that your answer below is correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [bug in Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5566). Consequently, it's a [bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773), too.

Comment: The answer is from 2010 and the bug's still there. :/

Comment: It's 2021 and STILL an issue. Unreal.